# useContext - Child component loses state after parent state is changed

Tags: reactjs

Here is a pseudo code example of my app structure. I am trying to share state globally with react context, but updating state at the top level is causing issues with Child components re-rendering and resetting state (I think).

```
// My top level where I store the state all other components need

function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState()

  const userContext = {
    userData,
    setUserData
  }

  return (
    <App>
      <Context.Provider value={userContext}>
        <Child />
        <Child />
        <Child />
      </Context.Context.Provider>
    </App>
  )
}



// My child component where I want to preserve state

const Child = () => {
  const [childState, setChildState] = useState('default value')

  // I want to keep this value
  setChildState('new value')

  // This is causing App.js to re-render, then Child to rerender, and I lose child state. Then on the next render my 'childState' is back to 'default value', when I want it to still be 'new value'
  const userContext = useContext(...)
  userContext.setUserData('some change to userdata')

  return {
    ...
  }
}
```

My questions:

Is this an okay app structure, or is there a problem with it? Is there something I can do to persist the state in the Child componenet, or do I need to move the shared state out of App.js somehow?

Comment: To start off you're not allowed update any state in your render method, which you violate in `Child`. Start by making a proper example.

Comment: Child wil always unmount when parent state changes, you can either move the child state to parent/context or try using external state management libraries like jotai

Comment: @super As I stated in my question, it is pseudo code. I wan't asking about syntax, but project structure.

Comment: @JackA7X I wasn't pointing out syntax. I was pointing out a structural error in your code that causes the behaviour you are describing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have structured the `useContext` wrong. You can check in React hooks how to use it.

One example with full-functionality which it may help you is:

```
const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [userData, setUserData]=useState('nothing here')

// any code you want to pass in the code
//e.g. a function
const randomFunction = ()=>{
//do something here
}

 return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
       userData,
       setUserData,
       randomFunction
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

then all you have to do is to wrap all the components (children) you want, e.g. wrap `<App />` so, more or less everything:

```
 <AppProvider>
      <App />
 </AppProvider>
```

So now in this case you can use everything from your `AppContext` in all your code, you can pass more variables and functions if you want, and you import that by using:

```
import { useGlobalContext } from '/pathYouHaveIt';

function App() {
  const {
       userData,
       setUserData,
       randomFunction,
  } = useGlobalContext();

// now you can use those like you have them set-up in the App()
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thanks! Solved my bugs right away and helped me clean my code up a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Provide state from parent to child like props, it wood be greater than useContext.

```
function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState()

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child userData={userData}, setUserData={setUserData}/>
    </div >
  )
}
```

And the child component has the form

```
const Child = ({userData, setUserData}) => {
  const [childState, setChildState] = useState('default value')

  setChildState('new value')
  setUserData('some change to userdata')

  return {
    ...
  }
}
```